# How to zoom a page in Chrome browser by Chrome API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an Chrome's extension, which can open a new tab, zoom in/out current page ... But i can't understand how chrom.tabs.getZoom() and chrome.tabs.setZoom() work and how to use them.
Here is my code, can you please help me:

```
/*Important when add envent click for button*/
zoomStep = 1.1;
tabId = -1;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

//getting tab's id
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
    if (tabs.length > 1)
        console.log('[ZoomDemoExtension] Query unexpectedly returned more than 1   tab.');
    tabId = tabs[0].id;

    chrome.tabs.getZoom(tabId, 100);
});

document.getElementById('btnZoomIn').addEventListener('click', FncZoomIn);
document.getElementById('btnZoomOut').addEventListener('click', FncZoomOut);
document.getElementById('btnClose').addEventListener('click', FncClose);
document.getElementById('btnNewTab').addEventListener('click', FncNewTab);
document.getElementById('btnReset').addEventListener('click', FncReset);

})


function changeZoomByFactorDelta(factorDelta) {
//if (tabId == -1)
//    return;
//alert(tabId);
var currentRatio = 1;
var ratio = 1000;
currentRatio = ratio / 100;
 chrome.tabs.query({ windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT, active: true },                function (tabs) {
    zoomtab(tabs[0], ratio / 100);
});
}

function FncZoomIn(e) {
//window.open("https://www.google.com.vn/");
chrome.tabs.getZoom(tabId, function (event) {
    chrome.send('defaultZoomFactorAction',
        [String(1.5)]);
   });
 }

 function FncClose(e) {
 self.close();
 }

 function FncNewTab(e) {
 window.open("chrome://newtab");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to fetch zoom factor in callback function

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
    tabId = tabs[0].id;

    chrome.tabs.getZoom(tabId, function (zoomFactor) {
        console.log(zoomFactor); //or alert(zoomFactor);
    }); 
});
```

log will be in background page (it will write zoom in a form 1, or 1.25 etc)

**edit**
btw. tabs API is not accessible in content script, only in background/extension script. Your document wrapper is wrong. Try to test code with toolbar button. Wrap it in

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
```

instead of DOMContentLoaded

**edit 2** (i hope I won't be flamed for this)

**manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "getZoom() test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
  "browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon.png"},
  "permissions" : ["tabs"]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
        tabId = tabs[0].id;

        chrome.tabs.getZoom(tabId, function (zoomFactor) {
            alert(zoomFactor);
        }); 
    });
});
```

on toolbar btn click, you will get zoom factor of the current tab...start with something like this, and then introduce you idea in it
*put some 16x16 px icon.png in your folder for button

Comment: can please you give me a full demo for this, thank you ?

Comment: I am so sory but your codes didn't work with my code, can you please change it in my code, please ? I really need this :(
source: https://mega.co.nz/#!zZFDiaQJ!_LnUtV14H1iyA2rGFODpk_K4NXA3bA0rCZUPqtIoFGA